# Printing a singular array from within a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am writing code that entends to print out the first singular array as a whole from within a 2D array.

```
string[,] customerNames = new string [2,2] {{ "Bob", "Smith" },
                                            { "Sally", "Smith" }};
Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ",customerNames.GetValue(0)}]");
```

Expected output:

```
[Bob, Smith]
```

Current actual output:

> Error: Specified file could not be executed.
> Array was not a one-dimensional array.

The first element of the array is a one-dimensional array, however it is extracted from a larger 2D-array.

Is it possible to print out an array like this?

Comment: You can use nested arrays `string[][]`, in that case every array element will be of type `string[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With multi-dimensional arrays, you'll have to index the items individually to enumerate over a single rank/column. Get the number of the columns using `GetLength(1)` and get those values.

```
var rank = 0;
var customer = Enumerable.Range(0, customerNames.GetLength(1))
    .Select(j => customerNames[rank, j]); // or customerNames.GetValue(rank, j)
Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", customer)}]");
```